# Session not incrementing correctly

Tags: php, session

I've been working on a little project that has gotten me turned on and off regarding mood. The problem which I've been having all from the start before I remade the application is that I try to increment a session called 'Score', but for some reason it won't increment. At a time I managed to get this working, but in the little time it did I didn't manage to find the root of the problem.

The application is just a simple word repeater/practicer. I have wordlists in .txt format which the application picks up, cuts out the lines and gives each word it's own session. Then it picks a random word and shows it to the user. If the word (array index) has already been used, it will be in an "used" array and cannot be chosen again.

When the user is presented a word, he is to type in the correct corresponding english (phonetic) word. After submitting the script will check if the POST value given corresponds with the answer stored in a session for that word.

Now, there is a session called 'Score'. This session is not changed unless User's Answer == Session's Answer (which is tested to work correctly). However, when those two answers are the same, the session does not increase. I have tried to use ++;, +1; and += 1;, none of which seems to be working. Also, I made the form submit to an external file to try and lessen the pain to see logic, in case you wondered.

I fail to see where I might have missed the logic and would be very grateful for any help as this project started off as something fun but has now just become a hassle:

Wordlists are structured like this: Cyrillic(RU) | Phonetic(RU) | English(answer).

HTML (index.php): http://pastebin.com/3ePLtzuj

PHP (engine.php): http://pastebin.com/pyXR2U2s

POST->PHP (wordcheck.php): http://pastebin.com/ZZxgkHkJ

Comment: I think you may have some logic error because `$_SESSION['score']++;` does work fine

Answer (score 0):

1. wordcheck.php: check if $answer == $result is really true: `var_dump($answer == $result);`
2. your engine.php isn't included in your wordcheck.php if that does matter
3. check the existence of your session vars, before using them - like: `$wordNum = isset($_SESSION['wordNum']) ? $_SESSION['wordNum'] : 0;`